# Extract certain value in column treeview

Tags: python, tkinter

I have tried alot of things but cannot get it to work. Basically what im trying to do in this block is create a button that will create a pdf of my treeview. All i want to do is for each row in my treeview that has data is to extract data only from one of the columns "line" and put into a pdf. is it because the line
`pdf.cell(200, 10, txt=word, ln=1, align='L')`
has `txt` which does not work with the string variable word? Help is appreciated!

```
def create_pdf():
    # save FPDF() class into a variable pdf
    pdf = FPDF()
    # Add a page
    pdf.add_page()
    word = StringVar()

    for line in tree.get_children():
        pdf.set_font("Arial", size=10)
        # for value in tree.item(line)['values']:
            # word = [set(value)]
        word.set((line, 'Line'))
        pdf.cell(200, 10, txt=word, ln=1, align='L')
    pdf.output("GFG.pdf")
    return None


createpdf = Button(frame5, text="Create PDF", relief=GROOVE, command=create_pdf, width=10)
createpdf.place(x=1668, y=10, height=30)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`word` is a `StringVar`, so `txt=word` is not working.

Actually you don't need to use `StringVar` at all.  Also you need to use `tree.set(line, 'Line')` to get the value of the column `Line` of row `line`:

```py
def create_pdf():
    # save FPDF() class into a variable pdf
    pdf = FPDF()
    # Add a page
    pdf.add_page()

    pdf.set_font("Arial", size=10)
    for line in tree.get_children():
        # get the value of the cell in column 'Line'
        word = tree.set(line, 'Line')
        pdf.cell(200, 10, txt=word, ln=1, align='L')
    pdf.output("GFG.pdf")
```